# How to Implement Error handling in Text To Speech while working with Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-text-to-speech

I am passing `TextToSpeech` from Fragment to my RecyclerView Adapter.
While passing it, I am also sending a flag `textToSpeechSupported` to confirm whether the currently set device language is supported for `TextToSpeech` announcement or not.

But every time the value of this flag is being set as `false`, even though I am setting the value to `true` in `onCreate`.
It seems there is an issue with my implementation approach.

But I tired to debug and also added Logs.
Also I did multiple test and tried various other combinations. But every time the flag `textToSpeechSupported` value is being passed is `false`, even if the language is supported.
Am I missing something here.

I need the flag `textToSpeechSupported` value to be `true` if the device language is supported by `TextToSpeech`

Please guide.

```
class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var welcomeAdapter: WelcomeAdapter
    private lateinit var textToSpeech: TextToSpeech
    private var textToSpeechSupported: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(requireContext()) { status ->
            if (status == SUCCESS) {
                val result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
                textToSpeechSupported =
                    !(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        welcomeAdapter = WelcomeAdapter(textToSpeech, textToSpeechSupported)
        binding.adapter = welcomeAdapter 
        
    }
}
```

```
class Welcomedapter(private val textToSpeech: TextToSpeech, private val textToSpeechSupported: Boolean) : ListAdapter<Welcome, ViewHolder>(WelcomeDiffCallback()) {

    //....

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ContainerWelcomeBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Welcome, textToSpeech: TextToSpeech, textToSpeechSupported: Boolean) {
            binding.apply {
                welcomeMessageText.text = item.welcome
                textToSpeechImage.setOnClickListener {
                    if (textToSpeechSupported) {
                        textToSpeech.speak(item.welcome, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null)
                    } else {
                        // Send an event for Toast saying that language is not supported for Text to Speech
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The objective/goal is to ensure that value of flag `textToSpeechSupported`  is correctly calculated and passed to Recycler View Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that onViewCreated is being called BEFORE the tts has had time to initialize, so you are accessing textToSpeechSupported too early and you're always getting your default (false) value.

So, instead of calling:

```
welcomeAdapter = WelcomeAdapter(textToSpeech, textToSpeechSupported)
binding.adapter = welcomeAdapter
```

from inside onViewCreated, make a new function:

```
fun thisFunctionRunsAFTERtheTTSisInitialized() {

    // put that code here instead.

}
```

And then call that function from inside your onCreate so it will run AFTER the tts has initialized:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(requireContext()) { status ->
            if (status == SUCCESS) {
                val result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
                textToSpeechSupported =
                    !(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA)

                thisFunctionRunsAFTERtheTTSisInitialized() // <---------------

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. (Point 1) Please note that If I keep the function `thisFunctionRunsAFTERtheTTSisInitialized()` inside the `if statement` then it will only execute if the `textToSpeech` status is `SUCCESS` and if the status is different then our `welcomeAdapter` will not be ever initialized. (Point 2) Is it okay to put recycler view adapter initialization inside `OnCreate` or should we keep it inside `onCreateView`

Comment: Point 1, you're correct.  I'm sorry I don't know the answer to point 2.  My answer is mainly to show that the tts initialization is asynchronous and delayed.  I would suggest posting any new questions separately and if you do that, include all code including the activity that contains the fragment.  There may be a whole different way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to pass an interface or function to adapter
e.g

```
class Welcomedapter(private val block : () -> Unit) : ListAdapter<Welcome, ViewHolder>(WelcomeDiffCallback()) {

    //....

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ContainerWelcomeBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Welcome, textToSpeech: TextToSpeech, textToSpeechSupported: Boolean) {
            binding.apply {
                welcomeMessageText.text = item.welcome
                textToSpeechImage.setOnClickListener {
                    block()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    welcomeAdapter = WelcomeAdapter {
        if (textToSpeechSupported) {
            textToSpeech.speak(item.welcome, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null)
        } else {
            // show the toast here now 
            
        }
    }
    binding.adapter = welcomeAdapter

}
```